# Sibelius seven - adjusting the length of one bar/measure

Tags: sibelius

I want to shorten the length of the final bar in the line, without any of the other bars moving. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

Turn on View: Handles.  You'll see a marker just past the end of the last stave.  Drag it across.

You can do this without making the handle visible, once you know where it is.[image]

The other bars in that line will re-size to accommodate the shorter line length.  If you want just one bar compressed,  Shift-Alt-LeftArrow and Shift-Alt-RightArrow will compress or expand the spacing of just a selected bar or bars.

http://www.laurencepayne.co.uk/sibelius.html#u

Comment: thank you Laurence. I am looking for a way to adjust the length of only the final bar. As far as I can see moving this handle moves all of the bars in the lin.

Comment: Shift-Alt-LeftArrow and Shift-Alt-RightArrow will compress or expand the spacing of a selected bar or bars.

http://www.laurencepayne.co.uk/sibelius.html#u